# How to create an output for the Design Automation API Workitem payload other than Revit file?

Tags: c#, autodesk-forge, autodesk, revit-api, autodesk-designautomation

I have created a plugin that stores family data in a list from the given Revit model. Initially I was extracting the data from the log of the Workitem on it's success response, but the data has become very large and the console is not able to write all the data. So if you know any way to get that data from the plugin, that will be extremely helpful?

I tried to add an output parameter/argument of JSON file type to activity/Workitem, but I but always get failed instruction as response. I am having trouble in adding the path for the output file in the plugin.

I tried to follow the CountIt example of the forge but I was not able to get the JSON result.

Here is the code I used:
using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText("result.json"))
{
sw.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(familyData, Formating.Intended));// familyData is a list of data
sw.Close();
}

Comment: Can you share the report log ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is typical Activity and Workitem.

Activity

```
{
    "commandLine": [
        "$(engine.path)\\\\revitcoreconsole.exe  /c \"$(args[rvtFile].path)\" /al \"$(appbundles[familydata].path)\""
    ],
    "parameters": {
        "rvtFile": {
            "verb": "get",
            "description": "Input Revit model",
            "required": true,
            "localName": "InputRevitFiles"
        },      
        "result": {
            "verb": "put",
            "description": "Results",
            "required": true,
            "localName": "result.json"
        }       
    },
    "id": "getfamilydata",
    "engine": "Autodesk.Revit+2021",
    "appbundles": [
        "appnickname.familydata+prod"
    ],
    "description": "Get's family data in a JSON"    
}
```

Workitem

```
{
    "activityId": "appnickname.getfamilydata+prod",
    "arguments": {
        "rvtFile": {
            "url": "urn:adsk.objects:os.object:cloud123456/c.dwg or HTTP Url",
            "headers": {
                "Authorization": "Bearer {{ _.oAuthToken }}"
            },
            "verb": "get"

        },
        "result": {
            "url": "URL with write access",
            "verb": "put"

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Madhukar but with few modification I was able to get the List data in a text file by following the CountIt example of the forge-dsign automation.